# Why replace missing values with -9999?

Tags: python-3.x, linear-regression, missing-data

Code for a Linear Regression model with numpy:

```
from statistics import mean
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

def create_dataset(hm, variance, step=2, correlation=False):
    val = 1
    ys = []
    for i in range(hm):
        y = val + random.randrange(-variance, variance)
        ys.append(y)
        if correlation and correlation == 'pos':
            val += step
        elif correlation and correlation == 'meg':
            val -= step
    xs = [i for i in range(len(ys))]

    return np.array(xs, dtype=np.float64), np.array(ys, dtype=np.float64)

def best_fit_slope_and_intercept(X, y):
    x_mean = mean(X)
    y_mean = mean(y)
    gradient_calc1 = x_mean * y_mean - mean(X * y)
    gradient_calc2 = x_mean ** 2 - mean(X ** 2)
    gradient = gradient_calc1 / gradient_calc2
    intercept = y_mean - gradient * x_mean
    return gradient, intercept


def r_squared(gradient, intercept, xs, ys):
    the_mean = mean(ys)
    regression_y = [gradient * x + intercept for x in xs]
    total_error = (abs(ys - the_mean) ** 2).sum()
    explained_error = (abs(ys - regression_y) ** 2).sum()
    return 1 - explained_error / total_error

xs, ys = create_dataset(100, 1000, 10, 'pos')
m, b = best_fit_slope_and_intercept(xs, ys)
regression_line = [m * x + b for x in xs]

regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(xs.reshape(-1, 1), ys)

prediction = regressor.predict(xs.reshape(-1, 1))
print(r_squared(m, b, xs, ys))
plt.scatter((xs), ys)
plt.plot(xs, regression_line)
plt.plot(xs, prediction)
plt.show()
```

1. With reference to this can anyone tell me why should I replace missing values with -9999 as sentdex did in his tutorial?

With regard to this, sentdex said that most algorithms recognize such inputs as outliers? Is there a specific handle for this or the does the math prevent the outliers from negatively affecting the regression.

2. Is this the method used in machine learning libraries for implementing Linear Regression or are other concepts used.

Video on Linear Regression from scratch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QUyAFokOmow&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDfKTOs3Keq_kaG2P55YRn5v&index=11

Answer (score 0):

1. Replacing all your missing values with 0 or -9999 help remove NaN numbers and thereby help your dataset to be normalized with a higher efficiency (if , you normalise your dataset) . Also , setting NaN numbers as -9999 helps your code consider that value as an outlier . [Click here for further information !](https://towardsdatascience.com/whats-the-best-way-to-handle-nan-values-62d50f738fc)
2. Yes, linear regression is a method used in machine learning . There are a lot of other processes such as decision trees!

Comment: 2. I was asking if the implementation of LinearRegression uses the same concept used in the code in the question?

Comment: I am sorry for misunderstanding the question!
Yes, the same concept is used @Dr.danks
However there are other techniques as well.